# Component gets null at first time while routing, Angular

Tags: angular

I have two different routing components named express, summary components.

While loading express page, it will automatically redirects to the summary page

Express page : `rootpath/express`

Summary page: `rootpath/summary`

For redirecting

```
this.router.navigate(/summary)
```

And it redirects to the summary page.

In summary page, have a template with `ngclass=somecondition: flag`

But when it tries to load the component was `null` for the first time. Hence the browser throws cannot read the property flag of `null`, because the component is null.

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Can you add some more information of the issue like you code and console error image that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you share a bit of code of your `routing`..

Answer (score 0):

If your component load without any problem then issue with a property declaration
could you add some code so i can understand more about your problem.
whenever a routing happen component initialized and call the constructor first.